# How to draw a gaussian curve in android?

Tags: android

I have to draw a simple gaussian distribution curve in android. A sample code will be a great help.

Comment: Nobody has answer that question yet search for [android]+gaussian in search bar

Answer (score 2):

Here is some information on drawing things in android:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html
And for drawing a curve you could probably use the [`Path`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html)-class to draw on a canvas as described in the above link.
General info on Gaussian distribution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_distribution

Answer (score 1):

You can draw gaussian curve by using log scale in x axiz . Take common log of x axis value and can plot y values. Can use Android chart engine libs as a reference

Answer (score 0):

It may be a very late answer. I recently tried to plot a Gaussian curve from given data. Maybe, it will be very helpful to someone.

```
val listOfDriverSpeeds = fetchListOfSpeedRecords()
```

**Step 1: Calculate `mean` value of the records.**

```
val iterator = listOfDriverSpeeds.iterator()
        iterator.forEach {
            Log.d("driverSpeed", "${it.driverName} driving in ${it.velocity} kmph")
            total += it.velocity            
        }
val mean: Double = total / (listOfDriverSpeeds.size)
Log.d("mean", "$mean kmph")
```

**Step 2: Calculate the standard deviation of the records.**

```
var sDeviation = 0.0

for (i in 0 until listOfDriverSpeeds.size) {
    sDeviation += (listOfDriverSpeeds[i].velocity - mean).toDouble().pow(2.0)
}
val standardDeviation = sqrt(sDeviation / listOfDriverSpeeds.size);
Log.d("StandardDeviation", "$standardDeviation")
```

**Step 3: Calculate the 7 sigma (3 +sigma, mean, 3 -sigma)**

```
val sigma = mean
val sigma1 = mean + standardDeviation
val sigma2 = mean + (2 * standardDeviation)
val sigma3 = mean + (3 * standardDeviation)

val sigma1n = mean - standardDeviation
val sigma2n = mean - (2 * standardDeviation)
val sigma3n = mean - (3 * standardDeviation)
```

**Step 4: Use the least sigma as the initial value and the maximum sigma value will be the final value. I m adding one more value to calculate the deviation with accuracy**

```
val initialProjection = sigma3n.toInt() - 1
val finalProjection = sigma3.toInt() + 1
```

**Step 5: Now the range is ready. We need to calculate the normal distribution for each range of records.**

```
val fakeProjectedData: MutableList<DriverSpeed> = ArrayList()

var k = 0;
while((initialProjection + k) < finalProjection){
    val fakeProjection = DriverSpeed()
    val projection = (initialProjection + k)
    fakeProjection.projectedVelocity = projection
    val normDistribution = calcNormalDistribution()
    fakeProjection.normalDistribution = normDistribution.toFloat()
    fakeProjectedData.add(fakeProjection)
    k++
}

val values = ArrayList<Entry>()

for (i in 0 until fakeProjectedList.size) {
    Log.d("Pojection", "item: $i =  ${fakeProjectedList[i].toString()}")    
    values.add(Entry(fakeProjectedList[i].projectedVelocity.toFloat(), 
    fakeProjectedList[i].normalDistribution, 0))
}
```

> 

```
private fun calcNormalDistribution(): Double {
    return (exp(((projection-mean)/standardDeviation).pow(2.0)* 
           (-1)/2))/(standardDeviation * sqrt(2*3.14))
}
```

**Step 6: Draw a Gaussian curve from the list of data using any line chart library. I would suggest Android MP [chart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). It provides a lot of customization.**

```
drawGaussionLineChart(values)
```

[image]

The actual normal distribution formula derived from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

[image]

You can calculate the values with any math library. If anything that improves my answer, please share with me.